# Equivalence Relation on $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Relation on $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$:
$$A_{1}=\{(x,y): x\text{ and }y \text{ are relatively prime}\}.$$
Determine which one of the three properties are satisfied:

$i)$ $(2,2) \notin A_{1}$. So it is not reflexive.

$ii)$ $(2,3) \rightarrow (3,2) \in A_{1}$. A_{1} is symmetric.

$iii)$ $(2,3)$ and $(3,4)$ $\rightarrow$ $(2,4) \notin A_{1}$. Is not transitive.

That means, $A_{1}$ is not an equivalence relation. Is it okay? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, absolutely right.

Comment: You have not shown that the relation is symmetric, you have only given an example.

Comment: @Nightflight thanks a lot!

Comment: @Servaes yeah you are right. I am now editing. Thanks !

Comment: Strictly, you didn't prove the symmetry of the relation, but $A_1$ is not reflexive, so it might not to be an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For point (i) your argument is correct.

For point (ii) You have not shown that the relation is symmetric, you have only given an example. Also your notation is a bit off; you want to show that **if** $(x,y)\in A_1$ **then** $(y,x)\in A_1$.

For point (iii) your notation is again a bit off; you want to give a counterexample by showing that $(2,3),(3,4)\in A_1$, but $(2,4)\notin A_1$.